# Cant export a mat module from material.module 'it was neither declared nor imported'

Tags: angular7, angular-material-7

I am trying to export a module from my material.module.ts while creating a mat table. But it doesn't display anything when I run the localhost as it gives the following error. How can I fix this out?

```
Uncaught Error: Can't export directive MatPaginator from MaterialModule as it was neither declared nor imported!
```

material.module.ts

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {
  MatAutocompleteModule,
  MatBadgeModule,
  MatBottomSheetModule,
  MatButtonModule,
  MatButtonToggleModule,
  MatCardModule,
  MatCheckboxModule,
  MatGridListModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatListModule,
  MatMenuModule,
  MatTableDataSource,
  MatPaginatorModule,
  MatRadioModule,
  MatTableModule,
  MatPaginator,
} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  exports: [
  MatAutocompleteModule,
  MatBadgeModule,
  MatBottomSheetModule,
  MatButtonModule,
  MatButtonToggleModule,
  MatCardModule,
  MatCheckboxModule,
  MatGridListModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatListModule,
  MatMenuModule,
  MatTableDataSource,
  MatPaginatorModule,
  MatRadioModule,
  MatTableModule,
  MatPaginator,
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule {}
```

Answer (score 2):

exports: [
  ...
  **MatPaginator**
]

You export modules - not directives, components etc. `MatPaginator` is not a module so it can't be exported. You also export `MatPaginatorModule` which is what you need.

Comment: So you mean I have to remove MatPaginator from exports and should export MatPaginatorModule instead?

Comment: Yes - remove MatPaginator - but you are already exporting MatPaginatorModule - so you don't need to add it a second time.